# Lower-Bound algorithm getting Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: c++, performance, time-limit-exceeded, binary-search

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

ll lower_bound(vector<ll> arr, ll tar, ll n)
{
    ll l = 0, h = n - 1;
    ll ans = n;
    while (l <= h)
    {
        ll mid = l + (h - l) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] >= tar)
        {
            ans = mid;
            h = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            l = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    ll n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<ll> arr(n, 0);
    for (ll i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    ll q;
    cin >> q;
    while (q--)
    {
        ll val;
        cin >> val;
        ll ans = lower_bound(arr, val, n);
        // cout << ans << endl;
        if (ans == n)
        {
            cout << "No " << n << endl;
        }
        else if (arr[ans] == val)
        {
            cout << "Yes " << ans + 1 << endl;
        }
        else if (arr[ans] != val)
        {
            cout << "No " << ans + 1 << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have implemented the Lower Bound algorithm without using the standard library. But Why I am getting time limit exceeded for the above code?

Is the STL's `std::lower_bound()` faster than the above code?

The above code is \$O(n \log n)\$.

Problem Link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cpp-lower-bound/leaderboard

Comment: [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) [omg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ZOMG) [TLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym) [WTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuck#Modern_usage) wat u mean TLE RLY ?!?

Comment: yes.. try submitting the above code.

Comment: @J_H TLE means Time-limit-exceeded for such challenges. STL is the standard template library for c++

Comment: The problem is that you are making a copy of `arr` every time you call `lower_bound`, because the parameter is passed *by value*. Make it a `const` *reference* and the TLE probably goes away.

Comment: May help your speed if you don't make a copy of `arr` when you pass it by value to the function `lower_bound`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Some style points**

The code is marked C++ so use *using* not typedef, and instead of long long I think you should be specific in your architecture type int64_t, [this is about int vs int32_t but the points apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197964/when-should-i-just-use-int-versus-more-sign-specific-or-size-specific-types) I'm not sure if there'll be a speed implication, but you could check out [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org) and check the assembly output and make sure they're the same etc

(I checked, godbolt.org, there's no difference between)

```
using ll=long long
```

and

```
int64_t
```

It produces the same assembler output thus no effect on performance, so you can use the more 'modern' syntax without performance penalty)

Variables could have more descriptive names and don't use *using namespace std* . I know it's a short piece of code, [but it's a good habit to get out of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Your IDE or TextEditor can be 'taught' to prepend **std::** to *cin*
, *cout* etc. and thus it doesn't take any more keystrokes to type.

Maybe a comment or two here and there explaining why you did certain things, helps (especially in the light of frugal variable names) when you come back to look at your code after a year or two away.

The code is nicely formatted, however if you're going to have some user interaction is it worth having a bit more than "No" or "Yes" ?

The comments have addressed your question, these are some extra bits.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> #include <bits/stdc++.h>
> ```

That's not a standard header.  It's an implementation detail of your compiler, and as such is not a reliable include from version to version, never mind for users of other compilers.

The correct headers here are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

---

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

This is a poor (and potentially dangerous) practice.  The name `std` is intentionally very short, so shouldn't be too much trouble to type.

---

> ```
> typedef long long ll;
> ```

Why are we obfuscating the code like this?  If we want an alias for this type, why give it such an unreadable name?

---

> ```
> ll lower_bound(std::vector<ll> arr, ll tar, ll n)
> ```

This is *nothing like* the signature of `std::lower_bound`.  Even considering the version that doesn't take a comparator, the standard library version is much more flexible, accepting *any* matched pair of iterators, and returning an iterator.

I can guess what `arr` is, but `tar` and `n` are mysterious, and there's not even a comment to help.  I had to spend some time digging into the implementation to discover that `tar` is the value we're searching for, and `n` seems to be a signed version of `arr.size()`.

---

> ```
> ll l = 0, h = n - 1;
> ```

One line per declaration, please.  Declaring multiple variables (even worse - 1-char variables) is harder to read.

It appears that you're using an *inclusive* range for search.  You'll find that *half-open* ranges are easier to work with.

---

> ```
>    ll mid = l + (h - l) / 2;
> ```

Well done for avoiding the common overflow bug here.  Though I'd normally use `std::midpoint()` to get the same result more clearly.

---

> ```
> std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
> std::cin.tie(nullptr);
> ```

`sync_with_stdio(false)` unties `std::cin`, so the second statement is redundant.  And since we never use `stdio`, there's nothing to be gained from untying it anyway.

---

> ```
> ll n;
> std::cin >> n;
> ```

Never ignore input errors - we need to be checking whether `std::cin` is `good()` before we use `n`.  This isn't just a one-off; the whole code is fragile this way.

---

> ```
>     std::cout << "No " << n << std::endl;
> ```

Why are we flushing output after every line, with `std::endl`?  Is there a reason not to simply write an ordinary newline (`'\n'`)?  If the writer won't produce our next input until it receives this output, then **use a comment to say so**.

---

> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Not necessary from `main()` - reaching the end of function has the same effect.